# Draw lines using PyPDF

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am currently merging two pages into a single page in PyPDF3 but I need to draw a line in the middle of the two pages. Is this possible? Below is the sample code for reference. Thanks in advance!

```
from PyPDF3 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from PyPDF3.pdf import PageObject

pdf_file = "Plan.pdf"

inputPDF = PdfFileReader(open(pdf_file, "rb"), strict=False)
outputPDF = PdfFileWriter()

for x in range(0, inputPDF.numPages, 2):
    page1 = inputPDF.getPage(x).rotateClockwise(90)
    page2 = inputPDF.getPage(x + 1).rotateClockwise(90)
    
    total_width = max([page1.mediaBox.upperRight[0],page2.mediaBox.upperRight[0]])
    total_height = page1.mediaBox.upperRight[1] + page2.mediaBox.upperRight[1]
    
    new_page = PageObject.createBlankPage(None, total_width, total_height)
    
    new_page.mergeTranslatedPage(page1, 0, page1.mediaBox.upperRight[1])
    new_page.mergeTranslatedPage(page2, 0, 0)    
    
    outputPDF.addPage(new_page.rotateCounterClockwise(90))
    
outputFile = "Merged_Plan.pdf"
outputPDF.write(open(outputFile, "wb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Line annotation: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/adding-pdf-annotations.html#line

It was recently added to `pypdf`. You might need to update your installed version.

I recommend to switch away from PyPDF2 / PyPDF3 / PyPDF4 towards `pypdf`.